# Is there any way to use same IP for several requests with GAE Sockets API?

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, channel-api

I'm using third party service that has own notion of session and expects all requests in session to come from same IP. They claim that it's a required security measure and suggest to use proxy, LOL.

Is there any way to use same IP for several requests with Socket API?

Interval between requests in session is ~10 seconds, so keeping connection alive and reusing it should work. I've tried to setup proxy module that runs single instance and uses HttpClient with connection pool. Logging shows that after first request connection is properly released and stored in pool. While doing second request I see that pool has 1 connection, but HttpClient says that there in no free connection for route and opens new. Probably route changes somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I solved this issue. Solution that I described in question was missing one step. As my connection was SSL authenticated, I had to use same context for all requests that I make.

Answer (score 0):

[It goes against the way App Engine is meant to work, scale-ability.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#static-ip) Spawning instances closets to the consumers and multiple instance will mean different IP's. If you want a static IP you will need to switch to [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/). Its a server VM that can have a static IP address. Or if your 3rd party service can take range you get get them from the link.

> App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application. In order to optimize the network path between an end user and an App Engine application, end users on different ISPs or geographic locations might use different IP addresses to access the same App Engine application. DNS might return different IP addresses to access App Engine over time or from different network locations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Spawning instances should not be a problem with single instance of backend module. I've updated answer with a note on my attempt to reuse same connection.